# Decrease icon size in lwc and aura

Tags: lightning-web-components, css

i am using `lightning-icon` and i want to decrease the size of it.

```
<lightning-icon icon-name="action:approval" size="xx-small"></lightning-icon>
```

The smallest size is xx-small, and i can't seem to make it any smaller. I tried modifying it in css, but it decreased only the background of the icon, without the icon itself.

How can i decrease the size of it?

Comment: With CSS you can do it with padding, example [`padding: 0.3rem;`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/TQaDZMjto/1)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add class and give appropriate `padding` to adjust reduce the icon within its container

HTML:

```
<lightning-icon class="my-icon" icon-name="action:approval" size="xx-small"></lightning-icon>
```

CSS:

```
.my-icon {
    padding: 0.1rem;
}
```

Comment: Note. this also works for Aura.